# Is someone trying to solve problems by building all possible proofs using all possible rules of inference?

Tags: turing-machines, incompleteness, provability, automated-theorem-proving

We obviously can construct a program that, starting with ZFC (or any other theory) axioms, would use all possible rules of inference to get all possible proofs constructible in ZFC. (There would be countably many such proofs.)

Now, with a Turing Machine capable of solving the Halting Problem, we would be able to easily decide upon every problem this way.

Of course we do not have one, but my question is:

Did someone actually build a program that is going through all those rules of inference, with the purpose of finding proofs of, say, the 20 most important problems in math? Without our 'halting machine' this proces can possibly take forever, but maybe we will stumble upon some of those proofs.

Comment: Brute forcing mathematics? I don't know if someone has or not, but I doubt it. I suspect such a machine would take a staggering amount of time to produce a proof of even a very basic result.

Comment: What is a "Turing machine capable of solving the Halting Problem"?

Comment: I am pretty sure someone has realized a turing machine enumerating all proofs. Of course , it will be far far too slow to be useful in practice.

Comment: You could solve all sorts of problems if you could solve the Halting Problem...

Comment: We can safely assume that a proof of , say , the Goldbach conjecture (assuming it can be proven within ZFC) would be too long to find it this way in a reasonable amount of time. But since we can mechanically generate all possible proofs it would actually occur in far future.

Comment: To give a feel for the problem here, in Bourbaki's "Elements of Set Theory", he estimates that the expression that the symbol "$1$" is defined to represent in his formalism would take ~$20$ pages of solid text to print (that estimate may be far off - it has been decades since I read the book - but it is an insanely long expression). In order for a mechanical prover not to be bogged down in such humonguous expressions, it would need to do what we do: use definitions to constantly replace huge but useful expressions with simple equivalents. But a mechanical prover does not know what is useful.

Comment: Careful .. this method of enumerating all possible proofs will not *decide* all problems .. it can prove all the consequences of ZFC; it cannot demonstrate that something is not a consequence, which is something a decision procedure would have to do.  Setting that aside:  I believe Scott Aaronson constructed a Turing machine that halts if and only if ZFC is inconsistent ... which I assume it does by systematically cranking out consequences of ZFC. But look, all of this is purely theoretical ... even modestly interesting proofs take zillions of years to appear using a brute-force method.

Answer (score 2):

This is called proof search, but the combinatorial explosion of possible proofs (and resulting "junk theorems") makes it practically impossible to find anything interesting by brute force.

Imagine your proof search program makes its choices by reading bits from a random number generator. Even if this is done efficiently, there are so many choices at each step that even a theorem we consider simple will use hundreds or thousands of bits. After a few hundred bits, there are already more possible proofs than atoms in the universe. Cracking an NSA-grade encryption key amounts to correctly guessing a 384-bit number.

So we need smarter ways to narrow the search instead of just using brute force. This is an active research area, and AI approaches are promising. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06972 .

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a [Turing machine which halts iff ZFC is inconsistent](https://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/vgimygpuwi). There are cited papers and blogposts, but it is related to the paper:

- Adam Yedidia and Scott Aaranson, [A Relatively Small Turing Machine Whose Behavior Is Independent of Set Theory](https://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf)

There is a well-commented program, based on similar principles, with comments explaining the encoding of logic and ZF axioms:

- https://github.com/sorear/metamath-turing-machines/blob/master/zf2.nql